# friends profile pics not showing with names in list view

Tags: android, android-layout

i am using two activities one is having login button which makes the user login into facebook and other is having listview. after successfull login the list view activity opens which should display friends names and their profile pics in a list view. but only name is appearing. can anybody please tell me where is the error in my code.

```
            public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

                private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] { "publish_stream",
                        "publish_checkins", "read_stream", "offline_access", "friends_photos" };

                public static final String APP_ID = "**************";
                private Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
                private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
                private ProgressDialog mProgress;
                private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
                private ProgressDialog mSpinner;
                private Handler mRunOnUi = new Handler();
                String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
                private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

                ArrayList<String> friends;
                String _error;
                // private String graph_or_fql;
                private ListView list;
                TextView tv;
                Button loginButton;
                private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
                private ContextWrapper uiActivity;

                @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
                    setContentView(R.layout.login);

                    friends = new ArrayList<String>();

                    tv = (TextView) LoginActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
                    loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_login);

                    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
                                facebook.authorize(LoginActivity.this, PERMISSIONS,
                                        new LoginDialogListener());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

                public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                    Log.d("FB Demo App", "onActivityResult(): " + requestCode);
                    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                }

                private class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {

                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        saveCredentials(facebook);
                        getAlbumsData task = new getAlbumsData();
                        task.execute();
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {


                                mAsyncRunner.request("me/friends", new FriendsRequestListener());

                            }
                        });

                    }


                private class FriendsRequestListener implements RequestListener {
                    String friendData;

                    // Method runs when request is complete
                    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                        Log.v("", "FriendListRequestONComplete");
                        // Create a copy of the response so i can be read in the run() method.
                        friendData = response;
                        Log.v("friendData--", "" + friendData);
                        // Create method to run on UI thread
                        LoginActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    // Parse JSON Data
                                    JSONObject json;
                                    json = Util.parseJson(friendData);

                                    // Get the JSONArry from our response JSONObject
                                    JSONArray friendArray = json.getJSONArray("data");

                                    Log.v("friendArray--", "" + friendArray);

                                    for (int i = 0; i < friendArray.length(); i++) {
                                        JSONObject frnd_obj = friendArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                        friends.add(frnd_obj.getString("name"));

                                    }

                                    Intent ide = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, FrndActivity.class);

                                    ide.putStringArrayListExtra("friends", friends);

                                    startActivity(ide);
                                    finish();

                                }
                                catch (JSONException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }


                @Override
                public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);

                    return true;
                }

            }


        and
```

the frnd activity which is having list view is:

```
        public class FrndActivity extends Activity {
            private Button continueButton;
            TextView tv;
            ListView lv;
            ItemAdapter adapter1;
            ArrayList<String> friends;

            private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] { "read_friendlists" };
            public static final String APP_ID = "***********";
            private Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
            private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
            private Handler mHandler;
            private ProgressDialog mSpinner;

            String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
            protected static JSONArray jsonArray;
            protected String graph_or_fql;
            private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
            private Handler mRunOnUi = new Handler();

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mHandler = new Handler();
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
                setContentView(R.layout.friendlist_screen);

                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                            .permitAll().build();
                    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                }

                Intent i = getIntent();
                friends = i.getStringArrayListExtra("friends");
                Log.v("SizeNext--", "" + friends.size());
                lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.friendsList);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),
                        R.layout.rowlayout, R.id.rowtext_top, friends);


                mSpinner = new ProgressDialog(lv.getContext());
                mSpinner.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                mSpinner.setMessage("Loading...");

                tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.friendsText);

                continueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.continueButton);
                continueButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent intent = new Intent(FrndActivity.this, LogoutActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();

                    }
                });
            }

            class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

                private final Bitmap Bitmap = null;
                final LayoutInflater mInflater;

                private class ViewHolder {
                    public TextView name;
                    public TextView id;
                    public ImageView pro_image;

                }

                public ItemAdapter() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                    super();
                    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                }

                // @Override
                public int getCount() {
                    return friends.size();
                }

                // @Override
                public Object getItem(int position) {
                    return position;
                }

                // @Override
                public long getItemId(int position) {
                    return position;
                }

                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    View view = convertView;
                    final ViewHolder holder;

                    if (convertView == null) {

                        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);

                        holder = new ViewHolder();
                        holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rowtext_top);
                        holder.pro_image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);
                        holder.id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
                        view.setTag(holder);
                    }
                    else {
                        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
                    }

                    String[] data = friends.get(position).split("~~~");

                    holder.name.setText("" + data[0]);
                    holder.id.setText("" + data[1]);
                    holder.pro_image.setImageBitmap(Bitmap);

                    String imageURL;
                    Bitmap bitmap = null;
                    Log.d("", "Loading Picture");
                    String graph_Api = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?";
                    String id = null;
                    imageURL = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=small";
                    try {
                        Log.v("imageURL--", "" + imageURL);
                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(imageURL)
                                .getContent());
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("And:", "Loading Picture FAILED");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return view;
                }

            }
        }

    if anybody find the error in my code then please tell.. i donot understand how to fetch profile pics. please do not suggest any other code different from this. i want to know where is the mistake in this code?

    this is my xml layouts:
    rowlayout:

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profilePicture"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rowtext_top"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="name"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="id"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    friendlist_screen has list view and
    login has only one button
```

Answer (score 0):

Your getting freind name using below code :

```
frnd_obj.getString("name")
```

So use below code for getting friend profile picture url:

```
frnd_obj.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url")
```

Comment: it gives error in logcat

 No value for picture
org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
 W/System.err(3109):  at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:573)
 W/System.err(3109):  at com.example.demo_project.LoginActivity$FriendsRequestListener$1.run(LoginActivity.java:178)
 W/System.err(3109):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)

Comment: Can you paste the error log here? and also paste your Json String

Comment: i have pasted it above your comment

Comment: Can you post your response.

Comment: here is the link of friends list screenshot.. it is showing only names not the profile pic.. https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0SLer-UMCs6Q3VZS3NMLUlQeFE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

First check if the imageURL is correct.
If it is correct look at this and see if you can make it work for you.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/